# Socket.io inconsistent send times

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Ive been experiencing some freezes in my web application. So I decided to measure the time between the packets that arrive on the client. The are sent from the server at a consistent rate: every 100ms

However on the client sometimes there is a 700ms difference between packets. I did some testing on the server side and the packets are sent consistently between 100-110ms

When this freeze happens, the client doesnt receive any packets for around 700ms and then receives 7 packets all at once.

Is this a connection issue or an issue with socket.io itself? I am using socket.io 2.0.3

The socket isnt sending too much data. This even happens when it is just serving a single client

Comment: It seems likely that its the OS, either on the client or on the server, that decides that these messages can be queued and handled "at once". AFAIK, such behaviour is out of Socket.IO's control. You should probably use a network analyzer to see what actually happens with the messages.

Comment: Well, if you are running this off a crummy server or computer, then it won't perform too well. What are the specs?

Answer (score 1):

My first problem with socket.io was building simple chat app, when i send too many messagens it freezes around 500ms, and sometimes send 2 equal messages when it was freezed, i end up figuring out it was a problem with my database connection and the way i was rendering the messages on the client. So it may be yours (or may be not).

And also it would be nice if you share you code so expert users can help you.
I recommend you to create another application with a simple/likely you socket request, if it run correctly you should check your code.